# How to blend two image

Tags: java

I want to blend two images together with a ratio of 4:1

the result should be something like this

[image]

So any ideas ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post some of your code? You will get a faster answer if you ask about the specific part where you have a problem.

Comment: well i dont know from where i start all i have done is to load both image :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question is vague, but you could use the 2D Graphics API

Take a look at [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) and [Compositing Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/compositing.html) in particular...

So using the following images (base on left, overlay on right)

[image: Base][image: Overlay]

```
try {
    BufferedImage base = ImageIO.read(new File("base.jpg"));
    BufferedImage overlay = ImageIO.read(new File("overlay.jpg"));

    Graphics2D g2d = base.createGraphics();
    g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(0.5f));
    int x = (base.getWidth() - overlay.getWidth()) / 2;
    int y = (base.getHeight() - overlay.getHeight()) / 2;
    g2d.drawImage(overlay, x, y, null);
    g2d.dispose();

    ImageIO.write(base, "jpg", new File("Blended.jpg"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Resulting in...

[image: Blending]

Take a look at...

- [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html)
- [Writing/Saving an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html)

for more details...